# Array.some gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

These are my mistakes that VSC writes.

```
if (array.some(typeof item !== 'number') || !(intNumber)) {
          ^

TypeError: true is not a function
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at addNumber (D:\ИРИТ-РТФ\3 курс\Тинькофф\1 ЛАБА 2 попытка\rtf-lab-1-master\index.js:7:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ИРИТ-РТФ\3 курс\Тинькофф\1 ЛАБА 2 попытка\rtf-lab-1-master\index.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

```js
function toArray() {
    return [...arguments];
}

function addNumber(array, number) {
    let intNumber = (number >= 0 && number <= 9) ? Number.isInteger(number) : false;
    if (array.some(typeof item !== 'number') || !(intNumber)) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const stringArray = array.map(parseInt) + number;
    return toArray(stringArray);
}
console.log(addNumber([1, 0, 9], 2));
console.log(addNumber([2, 5, 1], 5));
console.log(addNumber([1], 4020));
console.log(addNumber([1, '4'], 1));
console.log(addNumber([1, 2, 4], 1));
console.log(addNumber([0], 900));
console.log(addNumber([7, 1, 7, 7, 1], 1248));
console.log(addNumber([0], 0));
console.log(addNumber([0, '4'], 11));
console.log(addNumber([null], 125));
```

Comment: `array.some((item) => typeof item !== 'number')`

Comment: Yes, I can't how fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `some` must be a function ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.some) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)). You're passing `typeof item !== 'number'`, which is `true` because there's no `item` defined anywhere (`typeof` is okay with undeclared identifiers).

Pass it a function instead:

```
array.some(item => typeof item !== 'number')
```

That will make `some` check each item and, if any of them aren't numbers, make it return `true` (and thus make `addNumber` return `null`).

Live Example *(I can't guarantee there aren't* other *issues with the code, but the question's issue is fixed)*:

```js
function toArray() {
    return [...arguments];
}

function addNumber(array, number) {
    let intNumber = (number >= 0 && number <= 9) ? Number.isInteger(number) : false;
    if (array.some(item => typeof item !== 'number') || !(intNumber)) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const stringArray = array.map(parseInt) + number;
    return toArray(stringArray);
}
console.log(addNumber([1, 0, 9], 2));
console.log(addNumber([2, 5, 1], 5));
console.log(addNumber([1], 4020));
console.log(addNumber([1, '4'], 1));
console.log(addNumber([1, 2, 4], 1));
console.log(addNumber([0], 900));
console.log(addNumber([7, 1, 7, 7, 1], 1248));
console.log(addNumber([0], 0));
console.log(addNumber([0, '4'], 11));
console.log(addNumber([null], 125));
```

Comment: My task was "You need to implement a function that will take two arguments. The first argument is an array of digits from 0 to 9. The second is any positive integer. The method should return an array of digits from 0 to 9, which is obtained by adding the second argument to the number made up of the elements of the array. If there are elements in the array that are not numbers from 0 to 9, the method should return null."

For example: first four tests must be 
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 5, 6]
[4, 0, 2, 1]
null

But in code the conclusion is incorrect. Can u help me find problems in code?

Comment: @Никита: You might want to create a helper function which will turn, say, `[2, 5, 1]` into the number `251`.  There are many ways to do this, but I don't know which of them you've learned yet in your course.  Then you could add the result (if you haven't already hit an error with non-digits) to the second argument, and reverse the process to split the result back into an array of digits.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet check pls

Comment: New problem with: 
return stringArray.Split('').map(item => parseInt(item));

Answer (score 0):

Again... Mistakes.

```js
function addNumber(array, number) {
    let intNumber = (number >= 0 && number <= 9) ? Number.isInteger(number) : false;
    if (array.some(item => typeof item !== 'number') || !(intNumber)) {
        return null;
    }
    
    const result = array.reduce(function(sum, current) {
        return sum + current;
    }, 0);
    const stringArray = (parseInt(result) + number).toString();
    return stringArray.Split('').map(item => parseInt(item));
}
console.log(addNumber([1, 0, 9], 2));
console.log(addNumber([2, 5, 1], 5));
console.log(addNumber([1], 4020));
console.log(addNumber([1, '4'], 1));
console.log(addNumber([1, 2, 4], 1));
console.log(addNumber([0], 900));
console.log(addNumber([7, 1, 7, 7, 1], 1248));
console.log(addNumber([0], 0));
console.log(addNumber([0, '4'], 11));
console.log(addNumber([null], 125));
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?  `"Uncaught TypeError: stringArray.Split is not a function"`.   That's telling you that there is no function `Split` property on your `stringArray` object.  Since it is correctly an array, you need to look at the name you supply.  JS is case-sensitive, so `Split` and `split` are different.  That will get you through the current error, but there are still others lurking.  Please ask another question if you get stuck on one of them.